# Passing a date to URLconf in Django

Tags: django, django-views, kml, django-urls

I'm trying to use my URLconf file (url.py) to create a KML file of a query of all objects with date X. I'm looking to pass it in a YYYY-MM-DD format.

My urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('events.views',
    (r'^(?P<date>[-\d]+)/$', 'kml_date')
)
```

My views.py file:

```
def kml_date(request, date):
    venues = Venue.objects.filter(event__eventdate__date=date).kml()
    return render_to_kml('gis/kml/placemarks.kml', {'places' : venues})
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguments passed to a view are strings. If you want them to be another datatype (e.g. `datetime.date`) then you will need to parse them first.

Also, your regex is *far* too permissive.

Comment: You're right, I ended up needing

`(r'^kml/(?P<year>d{4})-(?P<month>d{2})-(?P<day>d{2})/$', 'kml_date'),`

Comment: for anyone reading this in the future, I messed that code up, it's this: `url(r'^kml/(?P<year>\d{4})-(?P<month>\d{2})-(?P<day>\d{2})/$', 'kml_date'),`

Comment: Didn't you modify anything in view? I also had date as incoming parameter but it gives me error got an unexpected keyword argument 'year'

Answer (score 0):

url(r'^kml/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$','kml_date'),